# Missing separator in makefile error message

Tags: makefile

I have project, which should be compiled without a problem, but after setting everything , I get this error message :

```
 Makefile:460: *** missing separator.  stops
```

I've checked the line but didn't get where the error could be , here a snap of the code, in which the issue occures:

```
    # Assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
define ASSEMBLE_TEMPLATE
$(OUTDIR)/$(notdir $(basename $(1))).o : $(1)
##  @echo
    @echo $(MSG_ASSEMBLING) $$< "->" $$@
    $(CC) -c $(THUMB) $$(ASFLAGS) $$< -o $$@     
endef  # here is the line 460

    $(foreach src, $(ASRC), $(eval $(call ASSEMBLE_TEMPLATE, $(src))))
```

any idea how can I solve this , thanks for any hint

Comment: is it supposed to be endif in endef  # here is the line 460?

Comment: No only ended the rest is a comment

Comment: make doesn't expect (or like) spaces in macro calls. Try dropping them and seeing if that helps `$(foreach src,$(ASRC),$(eval $(call ASSEMBLE_TEMPLATE,$(src))))`. What is the value of `ASRC`? Does deleting that `## @echo` line help?

Comment: @Reisner thanks I've tried it, this error is now solve but I have others to solve